# 'H' symbol as a power of matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

Here is capture of problem
[image]

That is what I saw while I was studying maximum ratio combining (MRC) in communication.
It is probably very simple and stupid thing to ask. 
I guess it is Hermitian of a matrix but i am not sure..
Here is entire content: http://www.dsplog.com/2008/09/28/maximal-ratio-combining/

Comment: Isn't that representing the Channel Matrix? See equations (5) - (8) here: http://new.iet.ntnu.no/projects/beats/Documents/MIMO_introduction.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right in that it is the [Hermitian transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).

Essentially, it is the standard transpose of a matrix, except in addition to swapping row/column indices, you also take the complex conjugate of the entry:

$$ a^H_{ij} = \bar{a}_{ji}$$